# SSS + fluid render issues. missing parts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, fluid-simulation

I am trying to render some fluid with SSS shader but I am getting some strange behavior.

On the left you have a screenshot of the preview and on the right you have the render where you can see the second column from the top and third from the bottom have clean cuts which are not suppose to be here.
[image: preview vs render]

Here are the things I noticed

- Applying the fluid simulation modifier fixes the issue but as I am animating
  it it isn't a solution
- replacing the sss shader to any other shader fixes the problem
- moving the fluid to another layer or around the place doesn't change anything
- Moving the camera around doesn't change anything
- On every frame the issue is somewhere else

Any Idea how to fix it?
I'm on blender 2.78c. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B71jdVFE0ObJY3RicDFsT2t4Tnc/view?usp=sharing) is a download link to the file, but beware, it's 3.5gb due to the simulations (7zip file)